# Why Drupal does not see permission from custom module?

Tags: 7, users

I tried disable and reinstall module, but with no luck, clearing cache does not work too. Module name is bip_menu_perm:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_perm()
 */
function bip_menu_perm_perm() {
    drupal_set_message('test');
    return array(
        'administer menu permissions' => array(
            'title' => t('Administer menu publishing permissions per user'),
            'description' => t('Users with this roles can edit menu publishing permissions'),
        ),
    );
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? This function does not invoke on permissions page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hook is called [`hook_permission()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) in Drupal 7, it changed names from [`hook_perm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_perm/6) (Drupal 6)

> This hook can supply permissions that the module defines, so that they can be selected on the user permissions page and used to grant or restrict access to actions the module performs.

Make sure you clear Drupal's caches once you've made the change so it gets picked up.

Comment: That's a thought! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned by Clive, it is `hook_permission()` in drupal 7.
Following is the example:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_permission().
 *
 * @return array An array of valid permissions for the mymodule module
 */
function mymodule_permission() {
 return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'),
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  );
}
```